# How can I mount partitions in a full disk image (i.e. image with partition table) with fuse?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, fuse, loop-device

It's a bit indirect, but it's possible to mount a partition with a disk image using `mount` or `losetup`'s  "offset" parameter.

I'm looking to be able to use fuse to do the same thing in user space

### Use Case

My use case is building disk images on an autobuild server where the build job is not allowed to have root permissions, and the server should not need a custom setup for particular build jobs.

Comment: I do not understand why you want to mount the image that has been generated.

Comment: To copy files over, chroot, rsync or otherwise backup, etc.

Comment: Also, deboostrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do with fuse, but would probably be cleaner with custom tools.

#### Solution

With apt-get-able tools the following kludge is possible:

```
mkdir mnt
xmount --in dd --out vdi disk.img mnt

mkdir mnt2
vdfuse -f mnt/disk.vdi 

mkdir mnt3
fuseext2 -o "rw" mnt2/Partition1 mnt3
```

#### Explanation

The basic idea is that fuse can be used to separate a full disk image in place into files that point to it's partitions. vdfuse does this, but is a VirtualBox tool and requires a VDI or VMDK file to work. xmount uses fuse to make a raw disk image appear as a VDI file.

Finally once the partition file is available via vdfuse, it can be mounted via an ext2/3/4 tool fuseext2.

It's ugly but it works completely in userspace.

#### Update

vdfuse should be able to mount a raw image without the help of xmount, but there is a bug which ignores the RAW option.

I tracked down and fixed the bug with a patch here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox-ose/+bug/1019075

Comment: Addition: it should also be possible to make a simple `vmdk` file which references the disk image as `RW 55296000 FLAT "disk.img" 0` or something like that (with extra headers and the correct size in 512-byte blocks) (I don't know if there's a tool to easily generate those).

Answer (score 1):

There is [pmount](http://pmount.alioth.debian.org/) utility that is  a wrapper around the standard mount program which permits normal users to mount removable devices without a matching /etc/fstab entry.

The only thing you need to allow user to use it is to add user to `plugdev` group.

Comment: Only works if the "device" lives in `/dev/`

Answer (score 0):

1. `losetup` the image
2. `kpartx -av` the resulting loopback-device
3. Use the resulting partitions from `/dev/mapper/...` as you would do with a physical disk

You can accomplish all these tasks using an executable automount-map.

A `chdir` could trigger all the above actions. Or use sudo for a setup/removal script. Or...

Comment: It seems that some/all of that would require root permission.

Comment: @Catskul set set up the above, yes. To use it no. But same is true for your image. How do you create root-owned files if you do not have root permissions?

Comment: fakeroot will allow such a thing.

Comment: Actually, after more reading and experimentation, it appears that fuse mounting allows you to modify files as if you were root without the use of fakeroot.

Answer (score 0):

Mounting thought loopback device with `offset`, might be helpful.

```
VDIfile=VirtData.vdi
mountingpoint=/mnt/VDI
offData=$( VBoxManage internalcommands dumphdinfo "$VDIfile" |grep offData | sed 's:.*offData=\([0-9]*\).*:\1:' )
offset=$(( $offData + 32256 ))
mount -t ext4 -o rw,noatime,noexec,loop,offset="$offset" "$VDIfile" "$mountingpoint"
```

More details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/45019/9689

Answer (score 0):

libguestfs now has a command `guestmount` which spins up a virtual machine to allow you to mount arbitrary partitions in user space.

Comment: One or two line answers are often not the most helpful. Consider expanding your answer with links, elaboration or documentation which support your suggested solution.